# Phalcon . How to get database name from mongoClient / service connection

Tags: php, mongodb, collections, phalcon

I'm using [Phalcon Framework](https://phalconphp.com/es/) with mysql and mongo database's services connection for the models of each type.
We made a mongo translations system associated to the models to save related translations to mongo db, apart from mysql model information.

With a mysql model, extending [\Phalcon\Mvc\Model](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html), I can access to database's name and other information through model's associated connection service like that:

```
$src->getReadConnection()->getDescriptor()['dbname'];
```

where $src is my Phalcon\Mvc\Model

But when I try with models extending [\Phalcon\Mvc\Collection](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Collection.html), I couldn't find any way to access to the database's name. I tried to do that through phalcon\mvc\collection methods like:

```
Abstract class Phalcon\Mvc\Collection

public setConnectionService (unknown $connectionService)
Sets the DependencyInjection connection service name

public getConnectionService ()
Returns DependencyInjection connection service

public MongoDb getConnection ()
Retrieves a database connection
```

But I don't get any good way to do that. How I supposed to get that information like in \Phalcon\Mvc\Model

Answer (score 1):

You will find the method `getSource()` in `Phalcon\Mvc\Collection`, which returns the name of the collection (table name).

Your Model class should inherit from `\Phalcon\Mvc\MongoCollection` which inherits from `Phalcon\Mvc\Collection`.

EDIT: Phalcon's MongoAdapter is part of the [Incubator library](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator)